# Cocos2D and iPhone's accelerometer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, accelerometer

good afternoon!

Today I've started to develop a game and I got a trouble. So, first at all I would like to say that I have no experience developing games...

So, I've a CCSprite in the layer and I want to move this between the scene with a margin (top, bottom, left and right).

The minimum X should be -0.8 (in X-axis using the accelerometer) and the maximum 8. The minimun Y should be -1 (in Y-axis) or 0 in Z-axis and the maximum 0 (in Y-axis) or -1 (in Z-axis).

Ok, knowing this, I've tried to do this using the range between minimum and maximum space and accelerometer value but I haven't getting this working vertically (Y-axis on the iPhone). Then I got a done code in the web but this don't works when I want to move the object to back (the object only goes).

Did someone know how to fix this?

My actual code:

```
- (void)updatePosition:(ccTime)dt {
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    float maxY = winSize.height - car.contentSize.height/2 - 20;
    float minY = car.contentSize.height/2 + 20;
    float newY = car.position.y + (carPointsPerSecY * dt);
    newY = MIN(MAX(newY, minY), maxY);

    float maxX = winSize.width - car.contentSize.width/2 - 40;
    float minX = car.contentSize.width/2 + 40;
    float newX = car.position.x + (carPointsPerSecX * dt);
    newX = MIN(MAX(newX, minX), maxX);

    car.position = ccp(newX, newY);
}    

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    float speedY = acceleration.y * 500;
    if(carPointsPerSecY < speedY) {
        carPointsPerSecY = MIN(carPointsPerSecY + 10, speedY);
    } else {
        carPointsPerSecY = MAX(carPointsPerSecY - 2, speedY);
    }

    float speedX = acceleration.x * 200;
    if(carPointsPerSecX < speedX) {
        carPointsPerSecX = MIN(carPointsPerSecX + 10, speedX);
    } else {
        carPointsPerSecX = MAX(carPointsPerSecX - 10, speedX);
    }

    NSLog(@"Acceleration: X (%f) - Y (%f) - Z (%f)", acceleration.x, acceleration.y, acceleration.z);
}
```

Comment: did you allow it to use accelerometer? Also, does the NSLog shows the accelerometer changing?

Comment: Yes, it's working. The problem isn't this... :/

Comment: what type is carPointPerSecX/Y?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you want but I hope this helps you with your end goal:

```
-(void)updatePosition:(ccTime)dt {
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    int margin = 20;
    float speed = 15;

    float maxX = size.width - car.contentSize.width / 2 - margin;
    float minX = car.contentSize.width / 2 + margin;
    float maxY = size.height - car.contentSize.height / 2 - margin;
    float minY = car.contentSize.height / 2 + margin;

    float newX = MIN(MAX(car.position.x + xAccel * speed, minX), maxX);
    float newY = MIN(MAX(car.position.y + yAccel * speed, minY), maxY);

    car.position = ccp(newX, newY);
}

//define in header: float xAccel, yAccel;
- (void)accelerometer: (UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate: (UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    yAccel = acceleration.x;
    xAccel = -acceleration.y;
}
```